# Query: list questions where the OP also left an answer

Tags: support, stack-exchange, flags, data-explorer

I *was-trying-but-failed-miserably* to assemble a query for Stack Exchange to display all the questions where the OP also wrote an answer.

Preferably, the query would hide the results where a question has been officially answered (by clicking the checkbox) by the OP.

This query would be quite useful to uncover **not an answer** posts, usually made by new users. A lot of times I see that they add more questions to the thread by posting them as answers instead of posting them as comments.

Can a [Stack Exchange Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/about) (SEDE) wizard in-da-house to help a brother out?

Comment: Due to the short amount of upvotes to the question (**2** by the time this comment was posted) it seems that not many people have connected the idea of finding **not an answer** posts to **useful flagging** to earning the **Marshal badge**. This formula is probably one of the easiest ways to contribute to the site while working to get the badge. This made things so easy that [I tried begging](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/112779/can-i-have-more-flags-please) for more daily flags (didn't worked though), after a week or so of flagging I earned the badge #99, uhuw!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Here's one i just wrote that lets you set a max score for the answer and max reputation for the poster](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/s/2116/questions-where-the-op-posted-an-answer)

[Here is a direct link with a default answer score of 5 and max reputation of 500](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/q/118193/questions-where-the-op-posted-an-answer?maxanswerscore=5&maxreputation=300).

And the original SQL:

```sql
SELECT TOP 1000 question.Id as [Post Link], answer.Id as [Post Link]
FROM Posts question
INNER JOIN Posts answer
ON question.Id = answer.ParentId
INNER JOIN Users poster
ON question.OwnerUserId = poster.Id
WHERE question.OwnerUserId = answer.OwnerUserId
AND question.AcceptedAnswerId != answer.Id
AND answer.Score < ##maxanswerscore##
AND poster.Reputation < ##maxreputation:int##
```

Comment: Thanks, it's never been easier to find possible candidates to **Not an answer**! A couple of days later and I got the **Marshal** badge. I would upvote your answer 10x if the system allowed.