# Can I have more flags, please?

Tags: discussion, support, flags

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can a Brother Get Some More Flags, Please?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/107769/can-a-brother-get-some-more-flags-please)

So I've used all my flags for the day. It's time to sit back and relax, or ... since I have some free time to spare, I could continue to flag posts and help keep SO organized.

Can I have more flags (since my flagging history is OK) ?

If not, why?